# Uncheck every cell on tableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, uitableview

Hey guys i have a UITableView that is using the UITableViewCellAcessoryCheckmark as a checklist on my app. I want one button that will erase each cells checkmark, Does anyone know how i can go about this? 
thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

You could uncheck all of them in your model (if you are using good MVC) then reload the table.
`[someTable reloadData];`

Comment: right, but my problem is knowing how to uncheck them. I have tried:

[cell setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

This usually only erases the last cell that was pressed!

Comment: it depends where you are doing it, you need to do it in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath after a reload will be called for each cell.

Comment: ok i tried this and its not working, i tried to do the for loop shown below but its not working and i put it in my cellForRowAtIndexPath: method

Comment: ignore that for loop, please post your `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method

Answer (score 0):

First, when you build/init the tableView, in the delegate method, add the cells to an array. Then you can use a for loop to run through the array like so:

```
for (UITableViewCell *cell in cellsArray) {
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
}
```

Comment: ok i tried this and it didnt work, i dont know why its not working. But i added this code into an IBAction method and it crashes the program. i tried mixing the code up different ways and it keeps crashing!

Comment: It's not working because the approach is backwards. You don't set a modern clock by grabbing its hands and moving them around; you use the proper mechanism. In this case (as Grady Player mentions in his answer), you need to update your *model* (the things the checks represent) then ask the table to reload to reflect the model's new state. ALWAYS.

Comment: ok, i kind of understand, but not all the way. Im a noob so could u please explain that in a different/easier way?? Thanks

Comment: Not really, no. You'll just have to dig into the appropriate documentation. The concept you're not grasping is the Model-View-Controller design pattern the Cocoa API follows. Read this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html

Comment: Okay I agree with the above: DON'T use the for loop. Why invent a square wheel when you have a round one? Put [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone] in the - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method. That method will be called every time the table view is reloaded. Simply call [tableView reloadData] to uncheck all the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

still need it ?
if so its go like this and its very very simple !

in your

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
```

add this method -

```
if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

and in your IBAction function just add-

```
[SomeTable reloadData];
```

this will clean all your checked celles.

Have fun !